# Store RSA keys in Airflow Connectors

Tags: python-3.x, airflow-scheduler, airflow

What is the best way to store RSA connectors in Airflow Connectors?

```
hook = BaseHook.get_connection("my_rsa")
key = hook.extra
```

I am using this way. However, the key is stored as String. What is the best way to convert this to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to secure RSA Keys... you should use airflow's crypto module

You can encrypt your keys and keep the encrypted key in an environment variable or in your own `airflow.cfg`

Do note that Airflow doesn't handle key rotation by default for you.

from the [docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/secure-connections.html)

Install crypto package pip install `apache-airflow[crypto]`
Generate fernet_key, using this code snippet below. fernet_key must be a base64-encoded 32-byte key:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

fernet_key=Fernet.generate_key()

print(fernet_key.decode()) # your fernet_key,keep it in secured place!
```

Replace `airflow.cfg` `fernet_key` value with the one from above. Alternatively, you can store your fernet_key in OS environment variable - You do not need to change `airflow.cfg` in this case as Airflow will use environment variable over the value in `airflow.cfg`:

```
#Note the double underscores 
export AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=your_fernet_key
```